# Joining data from two tables with different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am new to python and this is a sample code I got online.
I have two big data CSV files one from the database and another from the company metadata. I would like to compare specific columns in both tables and generate a new csv file that shows me where the missing records in the metadata are. Keeping in mind that the two csv files do not have the same number of columns and I want to analyse specific columns in both csv files.

These are the two csv files:

**csv1 copied from excel sheet**

```
start_time  end_time    aitechid    hh_village  grpdetails1/farmername  grpdetails1/farmermobile 2016-11-26T14:01:47.329+03 2016-11-26T14:29:05.042+03  AI00001 2447    KahsuGebru  919115604 2016-11-26T19:34:42.159+03    2016-11-26T20:39:27.430+03  936891238   2473    Moto Aleka  914370833 2016-11-26T12:13:23.094+03    2016-11-26T14:25:19.178+03  914127382   2390    Hagos   914039654 2016-11-30T14:31:28.223+03    2016-11-30T14:56:33.144+03  920784222   384 Mohammed Ali    923456788 2016-11-30T14:22:38.631+03    2016-11-30T15:06:44.199+03  912320358   378 Habtamu Nuru    913856087 2016-11-29T03:41:36.532+03    2016-11-29T16:33:12.632+03  914763134   2301    Are gaining Giday   0 2016-11-29T16:21:05.012+03    2016-11-29T16:37:27.934+03  914763134   2290    G   912345678 2016-11-30T17:23:34.145+03    2016-11-30T18:00:32.142+03  914763134   2291    Haile tesfu 0 2016-11-30T20:37:54.657+03    2016-11-30T20:56:16.472+03  914763134   2300    Negative Abay   933082495 2016-11-30T21:00:22.063+03    2016-11-30T21:18:44.478+03  914763134   2291    Niguel Amare    914270455
```

**csv2 copied from excel sheet**

```
farmermobile 941807851 946741296 9 920212218 915 939555303 961579437 919961811 100004123 972635273 918166831 961579437
```

I have tried this code but I am not getting the expected output:

```
import csv


def get_key(row):
    return row["!Sample_title"], row["!Sample_geo_accession"]


def load_csv(filename):
    """Put csv data into a dict that maps title/geo to the complete row.
    """
    d = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=","):
            key = get_key(row)
            assert key not in d
            d[key] = row
    return d


def diffs(old, new):
    yield from added_or_removed("ADDED", new.keys() - old.keys(), new)
    yield from added_or_removed("REMOVED", old.keys() - new.keys(), old)
    yield from changed(old, new)


def compare_row(key, old, new):
    i = -1
    for i, line in enumerate(diffs(old, new)):
        if not i:
            print("/".join(key))
        print("    " + line)
    if i >= 0:
        print()


def added_or_removed(state, keys, d):
    items = sorted((key, d[key]) for key in keys)
    for key, value in items:
        yield "{:10}: {:30} | {:30}".format(state, key, value)


def changed(old, new):
    common_columns = old.keys() & new.keys()
    for column in sorted(common_columns):
        oldvalue = old[column]
        newvalue = new[column]
        if oldvalue != newvalue:
            yield "{:10}: {:30} | {:30} | {:30}".format(
                "CHANGED",
                column,
                oldvalue.ljust(30),
                newvalue.ljust(30))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    oldcsv = load_csv("/media/dmogaka/DATA/week4/combine201709.csv")
    newcsv = load_csv("/media/dmogaka/DATA/week4/combinedmissingrecords.csv")
    # title/geo pairs that occur in both files:
    common = oldcsv.keys() & newcsv.keys()
    for key in sorted(common):
        compare_row(key, oldcsv[key], newcsv[key])
```

Comment: I'm not sure `&` is the right way to get the intersection of the two key lists.  Does that code even run?  It throws an exception for me...

Comment: as i said i am new in python can you please give me a solution t

Comment: `common = [x for x in oldcsv.keys() if x in newcsv.keys()]`

Comment: This data is illegible.

Comment: what are things that you wanna match..?

Comment: try using `pandas`

Comment: /usr/bin/python3.5 /home/dmogaka/PycharmProjects/camparetnz/comparetnz.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dmogaka/PycharmProjects/camparetnz/comparetnz.py", line 84, in <module>
    oldcsv = load_csv("/media/dmogaka/DATA/week4/combine201709.csv")
  File "/home/dmogaka/PycharmProjects/camparetnz/comparetnz.py", line 42, in load_csv
    key = get_key(row)
  File "/home/dmogaka/PycharmProjects/camparetnz/comparetnz.py", line 33, in get_key
    return row["!Sample_title"], row["!Sample_geo_accession"]
KeyError: '!Sample_title'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I want to match big data from two different csv file which has only a few columns that are alike - @Anurag Misra

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me out even with another version of their own code

Comment: @MirieriMogaka if you want to get help you can: read both files with `pandas` then post `df1.head().to_dict()` and `df2.head().to_dict()` and tell us on which column you wish to join the df. If you read the most basic introduction to pandas you can do everything by yourself.  [link1](http://pythonforengineers.com/introduction-to-pandas/) [link2](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-quick-introduction-to-the-pandas-python-library-f1b678f34673)